# iText XMLWorker CSSResolver produces different results on Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I have a feature in my website that allows people to paste html comments that are then output in a pdf report.
I have an issue that after upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8 (with no other code changes) the iText XMLWorker and CSSResolver seems to output the html tables in the pdf with really thick borders.

Java 7:
[image]

Java 8:
[image]

Anyone have any idea why this might be?
Are there new settings/libraries for iText for Java 8 that I am missing?

Is this a bug with iTextPdf?

**EDIT**

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-asian</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code used to process the user pasted comment:

```
            String commentText = itemComment.getComment();

            // CSS
            CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();

            // HTML
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext( null );
            htmlContext.setTagFactory( Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory() );

            // Pipelines
            ElementList elements = new ElementList();
            ElementHandlerPipeline pdf = new ElementHandlerPipeline( elements, null );
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline( htmlContext, pdf );
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

            // XML Worker
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker( css, true );
            XMLParser p = new XMLParser( worker );
            p.parse( new ByteArrayInputStream( commentText.getBytes() ) );


            String commentDate = sdf.format( itemComment.getCommentDate() );
            String commentAuthor = itemComment.getAuthor().getFirstname() + " " + itemComment.getAuthor().getSurname();
            dataTable.addCell(new Phrase(commentDate, labelFont));
            dataTable.addCell(new Phrase(commentAuthor, labelFont));

            PdfPCell commentCell = new PdfPCell();
            commentCell.setColspan( 2 );
            Phrase commentPhrase = new Phrase();
            commentPhrase.setFont( dataFont );
            if( !elements.isEmpty() )
            {
                for( Element element : elements )
                {
                    commentCell.addElement( element );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                commentPhrase.add( commentText );
                commentCell.addElement( commentPhrase );
            }
            dataTable.addCell(commentCell);
```

Sample html (these users copy and paste tables from Excel)

```html
<table style="width: 458pt; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="609">

    <colgroup><col style="width: 190pt; mso-width-source: userset; mso-width-alt: 9252;" width="253">
        </col><col style="width: 55pt; mso-width-source: userset; mso-width-alt: 2669;" span="2" width="73">
        </col><col style="width: 56pt; mso-width-source: userset; mso-width-alt: 2706;" width="74">
        </col><col style="width: 51pt; mso-width-source: userset; mso-width-alt: 2486;" span="2" width="68">
        </col></colgroup><tbody><tr style="height: 15pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="20">
    <td style="border: 0px navy; width: 190pt; height: 15pt; " class="xl77" height="20" width="253"><strong><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">ABC12345
        - 1234567890123</font></strong></td>
    <td style="border: 0px navy; width: 55pt; " class="xl66" width="73"></td>
    <td style="border: 0px windowtext; width: 55pt; " class="xl67" width="73"></td>
    <td style="border: 0px windowtext; width: 56pt; " class="xl67" width="74"></td>
    <td style="border: 0px windowtext; width: 51pt; " class="xl68" width="68"></td>
    <td style="border: 0px windowtext; width: 51pt; " class="xl68" width="68"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="20">
    <td style="border: 0.5pt solid windowtext; height: 15pt; " class="xl69" height="20"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Transactional Charges</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl70"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl70"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">VAT</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl70"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Total</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; width: 190pt; height: 9pt; " class="xl72" height="12" width="253"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Remove item (Labour only)</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; width: 190pt; height: 9pt; " class="xl72" height="12" width="253"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Emergency Removal (Labour Only)</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; width: 190pt; height: 9pt; " class="xl72" height="12" width="253"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Replace item (Labour only)</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Additional
        Visits</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£80.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£16.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£96.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Part A123</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Part B123</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Part C123</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Part D123</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Security</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Visit Requested</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£58.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£11.60</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£69.60</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Revisit</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Admin</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Category A
        Visit</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Warrant</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Change of Locks</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl69" height="12"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Additional Time
        on Site</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl73"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: navy windowtext windowtext navy; " class="xl74"><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">£0.00</font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>

<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: red windowtext windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl75" height="12"><strong><font color="#ff0000" size="2" face="Verdana">Total</font></strong></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: red windowtext windowtext red; " class="xl76"><strong><font color="#ff0000" size="2" face="Verdana">£138.00</font></strong></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: red windowtext windowtext red; " class="xl76"><strong><font color="#ff0000" size="2" face="Verdana">£27.60</font></strong></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: red windowtext windowtext red; " class="xl76"><strong><font color="#ff0000" size="2" face="Verdana">£165.60</font></strong></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 9pt; mso-height-source: userset;" height="12">
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: windowtext; height: 9pt; " class="xl71" height="12"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px 0.5pt 0.5pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: windowtext; " class="xl71"><font size="2" face="Verdana"> </font></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML & CSS files so that we can try reproducing this issue ? Also which iText release did you use ?

Comment: I have updated the post with maven dependencies, the code used to process and a sample of pasted html.

Comment: I can reproduce your reported issue with iText 5.5.6. However, with the bleeding edge build of iText 5.5.7-SNAPSHOT, the wrong output (with the thick borders) shows for both Java 7 and Java 8. This is quite interesting :-) but investigation might take a while.

Comment: Hi @blagae! Did you manage to investigate in the end?

Comment: I did not, sorry @PiersGeyman. I'll look into this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment to the question, we have a strange situation.

```
|Java    | iText 5.5.6 | iText 5.5.7
|7       | good        | bad
|8       | bad         | bad
```

It turns out after some investigation that the inconsistency in `iText 5.5.6` was created through our use of `HashMap`. In Java 7, the iterator went through a certain `HashMap` as follows: `border-left-style` first, and afterwards to `border-left-width`; in Java 8, it's the other way round. Since our code in `com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.apply.HtmlCellCssApplier::setLeftOfBorder` depends on the order of the iteration, our implementation was vulnerable to this change.

The behavior of `HashMap` iteration has changed in Java 8, as you can see in http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/hashmap/hashmap-changes-in-java-8/ .

We were aware of this and included a fix in `iText 5.5.7`, replacing `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap`, because the latter guarantees 'historic' iteration over the entryset. See https://github.com/itext/xmlworker/commit/92b2146bcb37b283863e24e5cb18ed661411387c . Apparently, this was not exactly the right move because both Java 7 and 8 get the wrong order now. I will add this to the development backlog and we'll try to fix this issue.

EDIT1:

Below is a minimal use case which we are trying to fix. It currently produces a rectangle around one of the cells, which of course shouldn't happen.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px;">a</td>
    <td style="border-width: 0px; border-style: none;">a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT2: The fix is available since iText 5.5.8, released on Nov. 27th

Comment: *Apparently, this was not exactly the right move because both Java 7 and 8 get the wrong order now* - The "wrong" order, `width` before `style`, is the order used in the OP's `style` attributes, maybe this original order is kept in the `LinkedHashMap`, and in this case that order is arbitrary. Thus, the code had better not depend on a specific order at all...

Comment: Yes, I implicitly meant that the fix should make XMLWorker's behavior independent of the order of the style properties.

Comment: Ah, ok, for a short time I had the impression you wanted to fix the order... ;)

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this. Can I do any temporary fix whilst the real fix is being worked on? Would parsing and reordering the style properties make a difference?

Comment: If it's very urgent, then you can switch the order of border-width and border-style (only in Java 8 and/or iText 5.5.7) as a workaround. But we're working on a definitive fix, and a new release of iText is coming up pretty soon.

Comment: @PiersGeyman are you aware that XMLWorker doesn't support border-style: none and border-color: windowtext ?

Comment: What happens if you have that combination?

Comment: I'd have to check, but I assume it either ignores them or uses a default value

Comment: BTW the issue you reported has been fixed.

Comment: @blagae: I have just tested with the new code and it all works great! Thank you! FYI, it ignored the colour it didn't understand.